# FreeBSD compatibility layer on Linux

Tags: linux, compatibility, kernel, freebsd, bsd

I am aware of *Linux mode* on **FreeBSD**, where **Linux** binaries can seamlessly be executed in FreeBSD.

From the [FreeBSD handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/linuxemu-advanced.html):

> In effect, there is a Linux kernel in the FreeBSD kernel. The various
> underlying functions that implement all of the services provided by
> the kernel are identical to both the FreeBSD system call table
> entries, and the Linux system call table entries: file system
> operations, virtual memory operations, signal delivery, and System V
> IPC. The only difference is that FreeBSD binaries get the FreeBSD glue
> functions, and Linux binaries get the Linux glue functions. The
> FreeBSD glue functions are statically linked into the kernel, and the
> Linux glue functions can be statically linked, or they can be accessed
> via a kernel module.

This is essentially an **ABI implementation**. I'm curious if there is an equivalent ABI implementation in **Linux** operating systems which would allow the seamless execution of **FreeBSD** binaries.

#### See also

> [Running FreeBSD binaries on Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/288989/running-freebsd-binaries-on-linux)

Comment: As there are no binary programs for FreeBSD that are useful to run on a Linux system such an ABI implementation would be pure academic.

Comment: @arved - Without such an ABI, you cannot run FreeBSD docker images on Linux hosts. Not a huge use case, admittedly, but it's more than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.debian.org/ports/kfreebsd-gnu/ :

> Debian GNU/kFreeBSD is a port that consists of GNU userland using the GNU C library on top of FreeBSD's kernel, coupled with the regular Debian package set.

I am not familiar with it, nor have I tried it, but there is much more information on this project on the various wiki pages:

- http://wiki.debian.org/Debian_GNU/kFreeBSD_why
- http://wiki.debian.org/Debian_GNU/kFreeBSD_FAQ

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem, as to userland it looks like Linux (glibc, system calls, the works).